# Google cloud storage Aws migration, how to get access/secret key?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow the migration guide here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/migrating

```
In your existing tools or libraries, make the following changes:
Change the request endpoint to use the Google Cloud Storage request endpoint.
Replace the Amazon Web Services (AWS) access and secret key with the corresponding Google Cloud    Storage access key and secret key (collectively called your Google developer key).
```

There seem to be two spots - the "google console" https://console.developers.google.com/ , and the "google apis console" https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0

Neither of them seem to make anything called a "Google developer key", or a access/secret key.  Help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The step-by-step instructions for generating the interoperable keys is here:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys

For posterity:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. Click the name of the project for which you would like to generate a developer key.
3. In the left sidebar, expand the Storage section, click Cloud Storage, and then click Project dashboard.
   This opens a new browser window that displays additional storage access configuration.
4. In the left sidebar of the dashboard, ensure that the project selector displays the project for which you want to generate a developer key, and then click Google Cloud Storage.
   In the left sidebar of the dashboard, click Google Cloud Storage, and then click Interoperable Access.
5. Click Generate new key.
   The access key part of the new developer key is displayed.
6. Click Show to show the secret part of the new developer key.

Comment: Thank you! :)  Was banging my head against this for awhile today - hadn't realized I could click the grey links under "google cloud storage" in the cloud storage's sub dev console.